# Change icon of application developed with react native

Tags: react-native, apk

I want to change my default icon's app to another one and generate my standalone app (with expobuild:android)

But when I add another image(capture) in my assets folder and replace it in app.js,it gives me an error:

```
{
  "expo": {
   
    "icon": "./assets/capture.png",
  }}
```

I tried many time with and without default icon (I have error just with new image) so i'm sure that error came from the change of icons.

Do you have any idea ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using a CRNA solution, there is an easy way you can do it. Just go into the **/assets** folder and just paste there your new icon, then rename it to **icon.png**, just make sure you already removed the default one. It also works with the splash screen.
But if you created your project with **create-react-native-app**, you need to do it separatly in Android studio for Android and Xcode for iOS. See more with this link wich helped me too.
https://aboutreact.com/react-native-change-app-icon/
Hope it's gonna help ... Regards

Comment: thank you it's the correct answer but first we have to delete cache using commande expo start -c

Comment: Thanks for that. Didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

I used this this [repo](https://github.com/lszyba1/resize-reactnative-launcher-icon?utm_source=stackoverflow.com) and cloned it, then run one line command to resize the png to all the different formats.

> bash resize.sh my-cool-new-app-logo.png

Then drag the folder over and merge/replace icons.

[quick insight](http://wwwhww.news/u/cwSNkeLNXf#How%20to%20modify%20or%20replace%20icon%20for%20reactnative%20app)